# How does int offset work? Does it offset a bit or a byte?

Tags: java, android

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html

I need to offset by one byte each time.
But does that mean that my offset is 8 (for 8 bits), or 1 (For 1 byte)?
The documentation does not mention that...